# Listview has only one item despite adding to the adapter's arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am having problems displaying items on the listview, after selecting to add an article from another fragment, the Collections fragment should check if it's null and append it to the arraylist. However when done so, the listview only shows the latest updated article. I'm not sure how to go about this...

```
public class CollectionsFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Article> mArticleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView lvArticles;
    private CollectionAdapter mAdapter;

    public CollectionsFragment() {}

    public static CollectionsFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        CollectionsFragment fragment = new CollectionsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collections, container, false);

        lvArticles = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvArticles);
        mAdapter = new CollectionAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row, mArticleList);

        lvArticles.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty));

        lvArticles.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Article, Article, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Article... articles) {
            Article item = (Article) getArguments().getSerializable("Article");

            if (item != null) {
                mArticleList.add(item);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            lvArticles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Article item = mArticleList.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("URL", item.getUrl());
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            lvArticles.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Article item = mArticleList.get(position);
                    createDialog(view, item);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        private void createDialog(View view, final Article item) {

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(getContext());
            d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_collections);
            d.setTitle("Remove article?");
            d.setCancelable(true);

            Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mArticleList.remove(item);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            d.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
public class CollectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<Article> articleList;
        private int resource;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CollectionAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Article> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            articleList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
                holder.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a_author);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a_title);
                holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a_desc);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.author.setText(articleList.get(position).getAuthor());
            holder.title.setText(articleList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.desc.setText(articleList.get(position).getDescription());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return articleList != null ? articleList.size() : 0;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView author;
            private TextView title;
            private TextView desc;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `item` is not null?

Comment: I believe so, since I have added the check to see if the item intent received is null...

Comment: Ok, than are you sure that call to `add(item)`  happens?

Comment: I originally made the arraylist static, but read somewhere this should not be done. When it was static, it worked but had duplicate article items...

Comment: Can you put your adapter code

Comment: the best advice I can give so far - separate data from `Fragment`. Implement some kind of persistent storage or at least `ArticleManager` singletone. `Fragment`'s lifecycle is complicated. It could be recreated at any time and your `List` of articles will be simply vanished.

Comment: Updated with adapter code

Comment: Would simply moving the private inner asynctask into its own separate class work as an ArticleManager singleton?